# Login Loop on Ubuntu 16.04.4 on Parallels

Tags: login, parallels

i know that there are many replicas of the same question, but I am stuck with this problem, as many others, with the only difference that my ubuntu is running on a virtual machine.

When i try to login, the system just gives me back the login screen, asking for the password.

I have tried to:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

and it did not work.

I upgraded and updated the packages but nothing. I also upgraded the Nvidia drivers as many had problems because of it.

Can someone please help me solving the problem?

Comment: enouch RAM/HDD space into you VM?

Comment: Yes, I use it for computational purposes and it I guess it has enough of those

Comment: Check you have space in your $HOME directory?  If you have no space (for use by gui in temporary work files) the login fails, and you return to the login page.   Check as @damadam has suggested  (using a tty/terminal)

Comment: I had enough, but to be sure I did sudo apt-get autoremove. Still the problem stays!

Comment: But you could login to do update and upgrade... how did you managed that if you can't login? If you do indeed able to login some how, create a new user and see if you can login as the new user. I suspect there something wrong with the user's configuration, not the system itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and fixed it by disabling disabling 3D graphics acceleration in Advanced VM settings (i.e. Under Hardware Tab and inside Graphics).

Answer (score -1):

I tried a bunch of things, but what ended up working for me is updating to version 18.04 through the command line (from login screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).